# How much should I rotate P around O so that D points to T?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, programming

How much should I rotate P around O so that D points to T?

O is Origin, P is point rotating around origin. D is direction that we are pointing. T is the target.

[image]

To rotate P around O we have

$$
P' = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_O\\
Y_O\\
\end{bmatrix}
 +
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_P - X_O\\
Y_P - Y_O\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have to find $\theta$ so that line $D'$ would cross $T$ and $P'$. but I'm lost here.

I also know this line equation from two points

$$
y-y_{1}={\frac {y_{2}-y_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}}(x-x_{1})
$$

I thought I could put $P'$ and $T$ in this equation but then I would have two unknowns. I can't solve it further.

**P.S:** I actually need 3d solution but 2d answer is fine if it can be expanded to 3d.

---

Here is what I tried. for the slope of the line we have

$$
\tan(\theta) = m = \frac{y_2−y_1}{x_2−x_1}
$$

If I put `T` and `P'`

$$
\theta = \arctan(m) = \arctan(\frac{Y_O+(X_P-X_O)\sin(\theta)+(Y_P-Y_O)\cos(\theta)−T_y}{X_O+(X_P-X_O)\cos(\theta)-(Y_P-Y_O)\sin(\theta)−T_x})
$$

Now that I have all the pieces $O, P, T$ how do I solve for $\theta$?

Comment: Check this link to see if I understand the question.  If yes, then I will try to write an answer. https://www.geogebra.org/m/rkn5tgm5

Comment: @Narlin Interesting game, Yes, I have the same problem i guess

Comment: You need to find a point $P'$ on the circle of radius $OP$ centered at $O$ such that $\angle OP'T = \angle OPD$ (the latter being a fixed angle. In $\triangle OP'T$, two of the sides have fixed lengths ($OP'$ and $OT$) and you know one angle ($\angle OP'T$). This should allow a solution for the triangle, although you are in the ambiguous case since the known angle is not between the known sides.

Comment: OK. You have confirmed they are the same problem.  Our approach is way different.  I can probably set up an equation with 1 unknown, "the angle", but the solution in my meager ability is probably going to be numerical (Newton). I won't get to this until the weekend, so if someone wants to jump in, go for it.

Comment: @Narlin Thank you very much, I realized that you approached the problem in different and interesting way. I never thought about it that way. It would be ideal to get the value in one calculation but iteration is also a solution ;)

Comment: @rogerl Thank you, I will think about that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $r = \overline{OP}$, $d = \overline{OT}$. Then $r = \overline{OP'}$ as well, since $P'$ is a rotation of $P$ about $O$. Further, $\angle OPD = \angle OP'T = \theta$ (say). Write $\varphi = \angle P'TO$. Then by the law of sines,
$$\sin\varphi = \frac{r\sin\theta}{d}.$$
Thus $\varphi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r\sin\theta}{d}\right)$, and then
\begin{equation*}
\angle P'OT = \pi - \theta - \varphi
= \pi - \theta - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r\sin\theta}{d}\right).
\end{equation*}
Thus one can determine $\angle P'OT$ from the given data; since $\angle TOP$ is fixed, we can also determine $\angle POP'$, which is what you need.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank's a lot https://www.geogebra.org/classic/rjv8q7ph